# Order by Position Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have created a query on Rails with Postgres database, where we want courses to be in order by position as data available in an array, in our case it is course_ids.
A course_ids array contains courses' ids in squences.

```
Course.includes(:course_series).
  where("course_id IN (?)", course_ids).
  order("position(course_id::text in '?')", course_ids.join(',')).
  order('course_name asc')
```

but it showing below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FrontendController#get_courses

PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  ORDER BY position 52 is not in select list
LINE 1: ...9)) ORDER BY position(course_id::text in '?'), 11,52, course...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "at_courses".* FROM "at_courses" WHERE "at_courses"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (course_id IN (52,11)) ORDER BY position(course_id::text in '?'), 52,11, course_name asc
Extracted source (around line #598):
```

Could you please share what went wrong here? Please go easy on me. I am not a technical guy.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `.join(',')`

Comment: Thanks @Philip I will try and let you know.

Comment: @Philip we tried the solution but it is still the same issue. Could you share if there is any other issue?